# definition of ‘class std::initializer_list<_Elem>’ does not match ‘#include <initializer_list>’

Tags: python, c++, gcc

I am trying to compile a python library using the gcc compiler (version 7.3.0) and I am getting this error:

```
/mnt/c/Users/lisa_/OneDrive/Documents/include/initializer_list:23:7: fatal error: definition of ‘class std::initializer_list<_Elem>’ does not match ‘#include <initializer_list>’
   23 | class initializer_list {
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command '/home/lisagoh/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc' failed with exit status 1
```

What does it mean?

I am using Ubuntu version 20.04 and Windows Visual Studios 2019.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that along with your question. If you don't develop that software, a bug report upstream may be the better approach than asking here. As a new user here, please make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask].